# parent's opacity not working on child elements

Tags: html, css, opacity

I have looked everywhere and cannot find what the issue is. I am setting the opacity on the parent element but the opacity doesn't seem to be applying to child elements.

Googling for the issue is only bringing up results like "How to apply an opacity without affecting a child element ". But in my case the child elements are "not" being affected when I need them to be affected by the parent's opacity value.

Here is the sample code:

```
<span style="opacity: 0.5">
  <div>hello</div>
</span>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code, or event better, create a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Comment: Added sample code, as it was marked as off-topic without the sample code, but it might help somebody so taking the time to add that sample code. however, LOL for off-topic :)

Comment: Great! That's how this community works. Your question probably will help to other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you put a block element (such as `div`) inside inline element (such as `span`) which is wrong from the first place.

If you put an inline element (such as `button`) inside an inline element (such as `span`) it works.

```css
span {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <button>Inline Element, works!</button>
</span>
```

Also, you don't have to replace the `span` with `div`, just set the `span` to `display: inline-block`.

```css
span {
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <div>Block Element, But parent span too. works!</div>
</span>
```

Comment: this also worked, thanks! just want to add that "display: block" also worked, I guess for the same reasoning as above..

Comment: both `inline-block` and `block` turn an inline element into `block`. (Also `flex` etc.) But, the important thing, don't put a block element in inline element. It may cause you troubles with the different browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your question. I have a similar problem when using Vue. At some point the span stopped affecting child divs. Perhaps some native class for span containing inline-block has been removed

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, looks like I figured it out finally...

The parent element was a **span** tag, changed it to a **div** tag and the opacity started working as intended. This was in chrome.

Just putting this out here in case somebody is making the same mistake.